# convert a list of tuples to a list of strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this list of tuples:

```
listoftuples=[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
```

Or maybe this:

```
  listoftuples=[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1)]
```

I am trying to get this:

```
['00','01','10','11']
```

with this code:

```
listofstrings = ','.join(str(v) for v in listoftuples)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `list("".join((str(a), str(b))) for a,b in listoftuples)`

Comment: All I see is :[<generator object <genexpr>.<genexpr> at 0x7f1d2e0d4200>,
 <generator object <genexpr>.<genexpr> at 0x7f1d2e0d4350>,
 <generator object <genexpr>.<genexpr> at 0x7f1d2e0d40b0>,
 <generator object <genexpr>.<genexpr> at 0x7f1d2e0d5f90>]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```py
list("".join(str(x) for x in v) for v in listoftuples)
```

Comment: Why `join` instead of `+`?

Comment: This doesn't work when I have this as the listoftuples : [(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1)]

Comment: @yoyo I didn't know you might have multiple elements in a tuples, check out the update

Comment: Why go through a generator instead of using a list comp?

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> ['%d%d' % t for t in listoftuples]
['00', '01', '10', '11']
```

or more generally

```
>>> ['%d' * len(t) % t for t in listoftuples]
['00', '01', '10', '11']
```